# ForFiles works in C: and Downloads but not in Documents folder in One Drive

Tags: path, onedrive, forfiles

I have a Batch file that looks for old versions of duplicated Access DB files on a shared account.
I can get it to find and delete files on the c:, and network drives, and in my downloads folder, but not on my Documents folder. I want to backup and clean up files in my One Drive so users can access them remotely if needed.

The `C: drive` version works great. But is on the local machine.
ForFiles `/P C:\COOP\ContactsDb_Backup\Daily\ /S /M *.mdb /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @file /q"`

I can get a version matching files in my downloads folder.
ForFiles `/P "%userprofile%\Downloads" /M *.mdb /C "cmd /c echo @path /q"`

But I can't get even a file match in my
ForFiles `/P "%userprofile%\Documents" /M *.mdb /C "cmd /c echo @path /q"`

I am constantly getting

> "ERROR: Invlaid argument/option - '@path'.

I tried using the %username% in the path `C:\Users\%username%\Documents\` as well but I think I don't really understand.

I can get it to work on the `C: drive`:

> (ForFiles /P C:\COOP\ContactsDb_Backup\Daily\ /S /M *.png /D -5 /C "cmd /c @file")

But not on files in `\Documents` for One Drive:

I have tried wrtiting the path to the One Drive files using:

```
%userprofile% (ForFiles /P "%userprofile%\Documents\" /M *.png /C "cmd /c echo @path")
```

```
%username% (ForFiles /P "C:\Users\%username%\Documents\" /M *.png /C "cmd /c echo @path")
```

I have tried with and without double quotes.
All the examples I can find are using `\Downloads` and that works fine for me as well.